# Performing a function on multiple files

Tags: java, android, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt multiple video files in a folder with the below code on Android. But my current code is not working as desired. The app encrypts one file and stops. Essentially the code should be able to go through a list of files in the given folder and encrypt each and every one of them. Would appreciate any help I can receive on the below.

```
package in.org.connected.hercules;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button encryptbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    encryptbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new EncryptTask().execute();

        }
    });
}


static void encrypt() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
    // Here you read the cleartext.
    File dir = new File("/mnt/usbhost0");
    if (dir.isDirectory()){
        for(File file : dir.listFiles())
        {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
            String fileName = file.getName();// This stream write the encrypted text. This stream will be wrapped by
            // another stream.
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/usbhost0/(enc)" + fileName);

            // Length is 16 byte
            SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("MyDifficultPassw".getBytes(),
                    "AES");
            // Create cipher
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
            // Wrap the output stream
            CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
            // Write bytes
            int b;
            byte[] d = new byte[16384];
            while ((b = fis.read(d)) != -1) {
                cos.write(d, 0, b);
            }
            // Flush and close streams.
            cos.flush();
            cos.close();
            fis.close();
            }
        }
    }
    public class EncryptTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog pd;

        @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("Encrypting your video");
        pd.show();

    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            encrypt();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        pd.dismiss();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: have you checked `for(File file : dir.listFiles())` is iterating over every file?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you encrypt your videos sequentially at only one thread(EncryptTask).
With each file, you need one discrete thread to encrypt. Change your code like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button encryptbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    encryptbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            encrypt();
        }
    });
}


static void encrypt() throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
    // Here you read the cleartext.
    File dir = new File("/mnt/usbhost0");
    if (dir.isDirectory()){
        for(File file : dir.listFiles())
        {
            new EncryptTask(file).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        }
    }
    public class EncryptTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Do encrypt file
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);    
    }
}
}
```